# error: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '

Tags: c#, azure, console-application, nuget-package

Following this MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started)/article, created .NET 6 Console App in Visual Studio 2022.
No Modifications has done yet.

While linking the given NuGet Package, I'm getting this `error: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project` in the package manager console.

**.csproj**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Also, I cannot see any Azure NuGet Packages in the Visual Studio.
[image]

Do I want to update anything here?

Comment: Check if you can see the packages in Nuget Package Manager. Refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/oUBuGHN.png)

Comment: Azure Packages I cannot see any in NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot see any Azure NuGet Packages in the Visual Studio.

There should be `nuget.org` in *Tools-> Options -> Nuget Package Manager->Package Sources*.

If it doesn't exist, click on `+` to add `nuget.org`and its source should be https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json as shown below:

[image]

Once you add `nuget.org`, you can see all the packages and install the required ones in your project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found the same solution 2 minutes ago. worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71084767/16630138

Comment: Hey @PravallikaKV, Thank you for your efforts.